# Wordpress sending “Delivery status notification Failure” to my inbox every 7 minutes

Tags: wordpress, spam

We are getting spammed from wordpress@domain.com going to jaqqscigs@gmail.com. Ive tried the MU plug ([Wordpress and wamp sending "Delivery status notification Failure" to my inbox every 7 minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18306176/wordpress-and-wamp-sending-delivery-status-notification-failure-to-my-inbox-ev/18798222#18798222)) but I got a parse error. Is there any way to just disable mail being sent from wordpress all together? We have changed passwords, disabled password ect..

Thanks!

Travis

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about wordpress and not a coding problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (not tested). Depending on your use, you may NOT want to throw the phpmailerException....

```
class fakemailer {
    public function Send() {
        throw new phpmailerException( 'Cancelling mail' );
    }
}

if ( ! class_exists( 'phpmailerException' ) ) :
class phpmailerException extends Exception {
    public function errorMessage() {
        $errorMsg = '<strong>' . $this->getMessage() . "</strong><br />\n";
        return $errorMsg;
    }
}

add_action( 'phpmailer_init', 'wpse_53612_fakemailer' );
function wpse_53612_fakemailer( $phpmailer ) {
    if ( ! /* condition */ ) 
        $phpmailer = new fakemailer();
}
```

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/53612/how-to-stop-the-wp-mail-function